# cookies set with php are being cleared on browser close

Tags: php, cookies

Using PHP 5.3.10 I'm setting a few cookies on login. However, no matter the browser, the url, or the additional arguments I try setting, the cookies are always gone when I close the browser and return.

In php:

```
setcookie( $key, $value, time()+2592000, '/' );
```

I've tried setting the domain, secure/http arguments but they don't seem to impact this.

I've tried this for Firefox 12, Safari, Chrome. None are set to clear cookies on exit/reboot.

An example of the http header:

```
Set-Cookie: authentication_key=24...b6; expires=Thu, 31-May-2012 22:49:26 GMT; path=/
```

When I close the browser and return the exact same address (no changes in http/s or www) the cookies are gone.

Comment: its a long shot, but if your server sends a bogus `Date:` header, it can really screw stuff like this up.

Comment: how are you testing that the cookie is gone?

Comment: In all browsers I open the inspector which shows the cookies for the current domain.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you set them not to expire, the browser or operating system can still delete them for a number of reasons, the most common a user setting.

Comment: This is happening for all users, not just me.

Comment: Weird. Also it is a good idea to use sessions for login systems instead of cookies, they are more secure

Comment: We do, this for people who want to be re-authenticated when they return.